# Reshape R dataframe from long format to a wide format

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I have a table I want to reshape/pivot. The `Agency No` will have duplicates as this is looking at years worth of data but they are grouped by `Agency No`, Fiscal Year, and Type currently. The table is provided below as well as a desired output.

| Agency No | Fiscal Year | Type | Total Gross Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W1000FP | 2018 | Dry | 1000 |
| W1004CSFP | 2018 | Dry | 2000 |
| W1000FP | 2018 | Produce | 500 |
| W1004CSFP | 2018 | Produce | 1000 |
| W1004DR | 2018 | Produce | 1000 |
| W1004DR | 2018 | Dry | 1000 |
| W1005DR | 2019 | Dry | 2000 |
| W1000FP | 2019 | Dry | 1000 |
| W1005DR | 2019 | Produce | 1000 |
| W1000FP | 2019 | Produce | 1000 |

Desired Output:

| Agency No | Fiscal Year | Produce Weight | Dry Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| W1000FP | 2018 | 500 | 1000 |
| W1004CSFP | 2018 | 1000 | 2000 |
| W1004DR | 2018 | 1000 | 1000 |
| W1005DR | 2019 | 1000 | 2000 |
| W1000FP | 2019 | 1000 | 1000 |

Here is the script that I ran but did not provide the desired output:

```
reshape(df, idvar = "Agency No", timevar = "Type", direction = "wide"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df1, names_from = Type, values_from = `Total Gross Weight`)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  `Agency No` `Fiscal Year`   Dry Produce
  <chr>               <int> <int>   <int>
1 W1000FP              2018  1000     500
2 W1004CSFP            2018  2000    1000
3 W1004DR              2018  1000    1000
4 W1005DR              2019  2000    1000
5 W1000FP              2019  1000    1000
```

---

With `reshape`, specify the 'Fiscal Year' also a idvar

```
reshape(df1, idvar = c("Agency No", "Fiscal Year"), 
     timevar = "Type", direction = "wide")
  Agency No Fiscal Year Total Gross Weight.Dry Total Gross Weight.Produce
1   W1000FP        2018                   1000                        500
2 W1004CSFP        2018                   2000                       1000
5   W1004DR        2018                   1000                       1000
7   W1005DR        2019                   2000                       1000
8   W1000FP        2019                   1000                       1000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Agency No` = c("W1000FP", "W1004CSFP", "W1000FP", 
"W1004CSFP", "W1004DR", "W1004DR", "W1005DR", "W1000FP", "W1005DR", 
"W1000FP"), `Fiscal Year` = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), Type = c("Dry", "Dry", "Produce", 
"Produce", "Produce", "Dry", "Dry", "Dry", "Produce", "Produce"
), `Total Gross Weight` = c(1000L, 2000L, 500L, 1000L, 1000L, 
1000L, 2000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I guess I didn't look at Tidyr cheatsheet well enough to find that function